# Jquery and Vue.js in mobile apps

Tags: laravel, mobile, jquery-mobile, vue.js, vuejs2

Less than one year I went back to the code world. I started studying backend tools and I adopted Laravel as backend framework. Now I have to study frontend and after some research I decided to study Vue.js. But does Vue.js completely replace JQuery?
I read some articles about how to use Jquery Plugins wiht Vue.JS. My goal is to develop mobile apps. Will I have to use Jquery or is there an alternative? My goal is application performance.

Comment: jQuery is just sinctactic sugar. Anything you can do with jQuery can be done with VanillaJS

Comment: If you are looking to develop mobile app then you might want to go for ReactJS.